# can I initialize 2 mongoose documents with matching ObjectIds?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I have a Content Schema.  If a user creates a Content document, they are able to edit it.  I want users to be able to choose whether they see the “original” Content, or the “updated” version of Content.  My idea is that when Content is created, an OriginalContent document is also created and both contain the same ObjectId.  OriginlContent will never be edited after initialization, only Content will.  Then based on which view the user chooses, they see either Content or OriginalContent.  Can I explicitly choose the ObjectId for OriginalContent so it matches that of Content?  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NO!!** Don't use same **ObjectID** on 2 different Object, what I would recommend would be you can structure your Object like this

```
{
    _id:ObjectId() 

    OrignalContent:{
        Properties of Orignal Content
      }

    UpdatedContent:{ 
       Same Properties with OrignalContent but Different values
     }

}
```

This way you can always get the `Item` with `_id` and choose either to display `Orignal Content` or `Updated Content`. This could be your dummy Item (Add many properties as you want)

```
{
   _id:ObjectId("5db9a2c5c58a7738508bc3ac")
    Orignal:{
          name: Jon
    }
   Updated:{
          name: Jon Doe
   }
}
```

This way you don't have to create 2 Object

Comment: I have realized that separating content into original and updated actually doesn't work with what I am trying to accomplish.  A user should be able to favorite a piece of content, and once favorited, this user should be able to view this content in the state that it was when it was favorited.  The user should also be able to flip to the current state if it has been updated....(continued in next comment)

Comment: What I’ve come up with is that when content is favorited it gets copied (not referenced) into a favorites array within each user.  Instead of a live ref between a user’s favorites and the actual content, there is a static version that is created (think of it as a snapshot of the content at the time it is favorited).  My issue is that the static version needs to have some way of accessing the live version so users can flip back and forth.  Is it possible to populate the _id field of the copied content, so I have the static content as well as a reference to the live content?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you make another question with some code reference so that's its easy to understand your requirements Thanks ( Pretty hard to understand by reading comment), some Pseudo code might help clearing up the picture